# the page keeps on reloading when i press the onclick button

Tags: javascript, html

i cant figure out how to stop the page reloading when i press the on click button... please if anyone can help tell me:)

(this is in html)

```
<button on click="My Function()">Try it</button>
<script>
function My Function() {
  var x = document.get_Element_By_Id("mountain_bikes");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

</script>

<script>
document.get_Element_)By_Id("mountain_bikes").style.display = "none";
```

i thought that this would show and hide when i toggle try it but it reloads the page every time i toggle please help!!

Comment: Function names cannot include spaces. Press F12 for more information :)

Comment: There are several syntax errors, but the reload probably comes from having the button in a form, which triggers a submit. Try `<button type="button" ...>"`

Comment: The built in function `document.getElementById()` doesn't include any underscores, are you using something custom or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a few errors going on here. Here's the answer:

```js
// My Function() to myFunction()
function myFunction() {
  // get_Element_By_Id to getElementById
  var x = document.getElementById("mountain_bikes")
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// get_Element_)By_Id to getElementById
document.getElementById("mountain_bikes").style.display = "none"
```

```html
<!-- My Function() to myFunction() -->
<!-- on click to onclick —>
<!-- optionally add type="button" -->
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<!-- Added for demo -->
<div id="mountain_bikes">
  My super cool mountain bikes.
</div>
```

As stated in a previous answer, it's just typos, but more than was mentioned. I'm sure you're still learning the basics, but this is something you should watch tutorials on, and maybe look at other people's code to get a better understanding of how `JavaScript` works. Your code works fine, without the typos, but this is something that's easily fixed by pasting the code into CodePen, or just running `console.log()` on your variables.

For future reference, you should also know about the `preventDefault()` function, that can be run on an event, like onClick. This is really only important in the case of forms, but if you run into other issues this may help. If you have a button in a form, but you don't want it to submit, make sure you include `type="button"` though. Here's how the `preventDefault()` function works:

```js
// Setting constant variables since they never change.
// Using querySelector() for simplicity.
const article = document.querySelector('article'),
      button = document.querySelector('button')
      
// Rather than using an onclick on the button in the HTML, I'm using an event listener to listen for the click event in JavaScript.
// This is the same thing as we had before, it just looks a little different.
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => { // Notice the e parameter. This is our event.

  // This prevents the default behavior of our click event
  e.preventDefault()
  
  // This is the same as the if statement, just as a terny operator.
  article.style.display === 'none'
  ?
  article.style.display = 'block'
  :
  article.style.display = 'none'
  
})

// No need to set the style to none to start, since that's put in the HTML
```

```html
<button type="submit">Click Me</button>

<!-- Here we set the display to none, so we don't have to do it in the JavaScript to start -->
<article style="display: none;">

  <p>Without the preventDefault() function, the button would submit to the form—or at least try to, since there is no form—which would change the query in URL.</p>
  
  <p>This could potentionally refresh the page, as is happening in your case.</p> 
  
</article>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "[Fix the typo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)".

Comment: @angel.bonev I agree. I added some explanation to give more insight than fix the typo.

Comment: You've done a great job, but still  i don't think that kind of question deserve it

Answer (score -1):

In your  tag, the onclick needs to be one word, like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try It</button>
```

Also, you shouldn't have spaces in your function names, I'm not a JS first guy, but I'm pretty sure no language allows for that (that I know of at least!)

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: yes i know that's what it is like in the main code but i didnt know how to meet all the code expectations and i think the i just had to highlight the code area this is my first post dont understand very well:)